# How to forward generic message in Akka?

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to forward all messages from actorA to actorB.

In the receive method of actorA,

I write:

```
def receive = {
    case _ => actorB forward _
}
```

but actorB does not seem to receive any message from actorA.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Your code does not compile... Do you mean `def receive = { case _ => actorB forward _ }`?

Comment: Yes i've corrected the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do

```
def receive = {
   case msg => actorB forward msg
}
```

I think  `actorB forward _` will just return a function (i.e. the forward function) without actually forwarding anything.